# Styling existing tabs look like radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

Working on a project that uses legacy code (javascript) and an ecommerece framework for logic which currently uses 'tabs'. The client decided they now want radio buttons instead of the tabs.

The basic structure is ul > li where the li's are styled and act like tabs with an href and styling classes ect.

Rather than trying to re-wire everything to function with a radio button, I am trying to find a way to style the tabs to look like radio buttons. Is it even possible?

Comment: Check out this pen, this person has done something that might work for you
https://codepen.io/AngelaVelasquez/pen/Eypnq

Comment: thanks but it uses radio buttons and just restyles them. I want to make something look like a radio button that isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a link to show you how to do it:

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><div class="middle"></div></li>
    <li><div class="middle"></div></li>
    <li><div class="middle"></div></li>
   </ul>
</body>

 li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%
 }
.middle {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: black;
    margin:5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    visibility: hidden;
}

 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('li').on('click', function () {
            $('.middle').css({
                'visibility': 'hidden'
            })
            $(this).children().css({
                'visibility': 'visible'
            });
        });
    });

https://jsfiddle.net/2zavkjjf/
```